# Why use sha256WithRSAEncryption for ECDSA certificate?

Tags: ecdsa

I am trying to understand the use of ECDSA key based certificate that is issued (ie. signed) by a CA using RSA key. For example when you connect to [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com):

```
$ openssl s_client  -connect  www.facebook.com:443
```

You get the cipher suite used as ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256. So it means it used ECDSA key for server authentication. However, if you look at the server certificate here, you would see Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption, meaning it is signed using RSA key.

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            0c:1b:54:74:2f:1c:31:a6:c7:90:2f:1b:65:86:a7:e1
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun  4 00:00:00 2022 GMT
            Not After : Sep  2 23:59:59 2022 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=Menlo Park, O=Facebook, Inc., CN=*.facebook.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:24:c8:04:40:24:b1:2b:4f:20:b6:a3:32:b3:94:
                    d5:72:84:bc:3d:50:e0:d4:92:78:fd:7e:f5:96:08:
                    83:a5:aa:a5:e2:79:7d:ea:19:85:92:d6:e2:0e:ea:
                    b8:71:12:d9:ed:4b:6c:a9:ed:d5:14:a8:dd:d0:4b:
                    fa:8d:4a:58:35
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:51:68:FF:90:AF:02:07:75:3C:CC:D9:65:64:62:A2:12:B8:59:72:3B

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                3B:D9:84:5E:21:B3:62:D1:BC:0B:EB:8A:32:89:6C:F0:28:3A:50:0A
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:*.facebook.com, DNS:*.facebook.net, DNS:*.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.fbsbx.com, DNS:*.m.facebook.com, DNS:*.messenger.com, DNS:*.xx.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.xy.fbcdn.net, DNS:*.xz.fbcdn.net, DNS:facebook.com, DNS:messenger.com
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl3.digicert.com/sha2-ha-server-g6.crl

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl4.digicert.com/sha2-ha-server-g6.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies:
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.2
                  CPS: http://www.digicert.com/CPS

            Authority Information Access:
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.digicert.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2:
                ...l.j.w.)y...99!.Vs.c.w..W}.`
..M]&\%]......,X.......H0F.!..6m.#.u.kE.g.......S.#.!...4..h..!..Ca..B{.=f.v.W9=..j%..........b>.v.A...."FJ...:.B.^N1.....K.h..b.......,X.......G0E. ..SWQ_o..Ov....<*.....X"......le.!....~l...@[.}.E.........!<.......b,(w.J.>A....0.q.!..i..aA.M.u1XZ..,~.....*H)..~fg...!..
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         ab:5b:e0:a0:43:b5:15:26:fa:7d:b3:03:14:54:5c:6b:b4:fd:
         c4:6e:35:8d:8d:1a:5c:80:09:af:48:a0:4f:cc:ef:ff:e8:c2:
         c9:3d:59:a9:95:03:6c:3d:78:04:35:e8:c7:55:5e:ae:16:5a:
         d6:90:3b:23:bc:25:49:7d:a6:3c:10:1d:17:2f:00:c4:07:3b:
         59:15:9c:88:5c:1d:8d:8a:83:30:6a:e2:bc:99:13:3f:8b:9f:
         f8:a2:99:71:ea:97:b7:fb:48:48:79:8b:e8:23:c5:c5:fc:55:
         d0:8e:85:ed:95:07:af:b0:51:1e:0a:c9:0c:40:7e:fa:c6:86:
         b7:30:2b:02:2c:5d:db:ba:07:73:2b:b0:95:cb:86:46:a6:60:
         d7:be:10:85:55:77:ca:e9:97:84:d2:dc:00:d6:7b:97:90:06:
         50:40:09:aa:68:9d:c2:29:b0:db:00:c9:1b:e4:18:06:04:cf:
         38:de:dc:05:b7:b4:67:ed:15:ae:c7:b8:b0:4a:6c:12:6f:f8:
         ec:6a:d9:69:57:0f:f7:99:b2:05:14:35:5c:95:f8:f9:02:0f:
         ae:48:7d:5a:91:16:cd:1a:fd:a8:63:b7:97:4f:31:4d:dd:ff:
         f1:b3:ea:79:32:18:44:fc:a7:37:3e:65:a3:15:4e:d4:30:39:
         d3:d7:ee:83
```

So the client must be verifying the sha256 digest with CA's RSA (public) key. But then why is the ciphersuite still saying ECDSA being used here? What is ECDSA being used here for? Can someone clarify?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/253933/4249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it appears that in the ServerKeyExchange message, parameters are signed with the server's private key (which is ECDSA key here) and can be verified using the server's public key. So this appears to be the real use of the server's ECDSA private key, rather than any symmetric key derivation.

Answer (score 0):

The public key is indeed ECDSA but the ca that signed the certificate is using RSA key to sign it. That is just the signature that says it can be trusted. It has nothing to do with the actual key being signed. You are still using ECDSA for the actual encryption.

So to clarify:

The ECDSA is used here for public key encryption.  In most cases public key encryption is too slow for practical purpose like web server encryption with SSL/TLS.  In this case the web server and client use the public key to securely pass a symmetric key that is much more efficient.  So that symmetric key is encrypted using the ECDSA public key.

Strictly speaking the symmetric key can be securely passed between the client and server without validation of the signature on the public key.  The encryption is valid and secure.

However, without a signed public key there can be no trust that the public key belongs to the server/organisation that it is stating it belongs to.  In general terms, the chain of trust.  A certificate is essentially a public key that has been signed by a private key.  The signature is meant to allow you to trust the key.

CAs were created to be trusted 3rd parties that perform the signature of the public key.  The signature has nothing to do with the actual key type being signed or the encryption algorithms that the key will use.  It is simply a signature by the trusted (hopefully) 3rd party.  The type of key being used by the third party will determine the algorithm and type of signature.

Hope that is clearer.

Comment: >>You are still using ECDSA for the actual encryption.

Encryption of what? Key exchange here is ECDHE, so that is ephemeral and very different from the ECDSA key of the certificate right? What is the certificate ECDSA key being used for?

Comment: True, I was focused on the question of the RSA key.  I will clarify my response

Comment: "In this case the web server and client use the public key to securely pass a symmetric key that is much more efficient. So that symmetric key is encrypted using the ECDSA public key." -> If you see the ciphersuite used it is using ECDHE key exchange, which does not involve encryption - client and server just derive it using their secret (symmetric encryption key) at their end only using DH params exchanged in clear text before in the handshake process. Which symmentric key you are referring to here then?